# Difference between these two codes

Tags: java

What is the difference between these two codes?

**1st code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.math.*;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arr[][] = new int[6][6];
        int MAXsum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < 6; j++){
                arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1;i<=4;i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j<=4;j++)
            {

                sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i-1][j-1] + arr[i-1][j] + arr[i-1][j+1] + arr[i+1][j-1] + arr[i+1][j] + arr[i+1][j+1];

                if(sum > MAXsum)
                    MAXsum = sum;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(MAXsum);
    }
}
```

**2nd code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.math.*;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arr[][] = new int[6][6];
        int MAXsum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < 6; j++){
                arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1;i<=4;i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j<=4;j++)
            {

                sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i-1][j-1] + arr[i-1][j] + arr[i-1][j+1] + arr[i+1][j-1] + arr[i+1][j] + arr[i+1][j+1];

                if(sum > MAXsum)
                    MAXsum = sum;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(MAXsum);
    }
}
```

**--->** The only diff is in the MAXsum declaration then how both differ from each other?

**Note:**
The 1st code runs all test cases successfully and the second code does not run all test cases.

Comment: print out the value right after you set the original value, if you still don't see the difference by then ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.MIN_VALUE` is the least possible number, which is **Negative**. In the test cases, the sum might be negative and 0 is greater than that. So 0 gets returned instead of the negative sum.